# how to save oracle SQL queries automatically when a query is executed?

Tags: oracle, save

I want to save SQL/PLSQL queries, which are being executed by a user.

I use the below, and have to use `append` at the end of the statement as well as saving at the beginning. But, it's headache to execute a save statement all the time after a query is executed.

I'd like to know if there is there any command that would automatically save the queries to the file.

```
    SQL> save C:\savesueryfolder\first.sql;
    SQL> select * from emp;
    SQL> save C:\savesueryfolder\first.sql append;
```

Comment: Try the `spool` command `http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-sqlplus.html`

Comment: still need to execute the spool query every time to save. But Friend I don't want to execute the spool/save query every time. any clue here...

Comment: A.B.Cade is correct, just issue spool once in your session and it will save all the queries and results. Keep in mind that sql*plus does not flush the file automatically, so you won't see the queries/results in the file until you do either "spool off" or spool to a different file name.
But of course any other spool command breaks this approach, so this is more of a workaround than actual solution.

Comment: Thanks for valuable time to help me out. A.B cade and GWu

Answer (score 0):

Try for SPOOL command. SPOOL command  save the output into a file. you can apply following steps-

STEP 1:

Provide the location where you want to spool the output.

```
sql> SPOOL C:\Users\Anant\Desktop\temp.text
```

(or temp.doc depends with which extension you want to save.I recommend to go for.doc)

If `temp.doc/temp.txt` is already available then it just override the file, so be careful always try to create a new file.

STEP 2:

execute queries .

```
sql> SELECT * FROM EMP;
```

You can execute any number of queries.

STEP 3:

close the spool.

```
sql>SPOOL OFF
```

go to specified
location and check the file.